# Best way to migrate eclipse installtion to another computer

Tags: eclipse

as I need to switch computers (hardware), I would like to migrate my Eclipse installation:
Git/Maven setup, workspace, project settings and so on.

I have read a few hints about this and what I gathered is that copying the workspace completely is the best way to do.
Now most of the threads are already a few years old.
Will this work if I install Eclipse again from scratch or should I copy my Eclipse installation as well?
Or is there actually a better way by now?

Comment: Copying the whole workspace has never been and is not a good idea (I doubt that this is documented that way). There are import/export function for preferences, projects and an import function for plug-ins from an exiting installation (but make sure not to use outdated software). Git and Maven are built into Eclipse, so there is no need to install them separately.

Comment: No, its not documented, but has been given as answers here pretty often.
I have gone the way of exporting everything as you suggested and am keeping my fingers crossed that I have not forgotten anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the best way appears to be:

1. export the preferences
2. export the projects